# How to get and set style attribute in code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Suppose the following code:

```
          <MyCustomComponent
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_default"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In the custom component I have an EditText which I need to set its style attribute to `@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline` in java code, according to the `style` attribute in the layout. How can I do that?

I am creating a custom component therefore I also need to know which style has been selected in layout by user of my component.
Is it available through `AttributeSet`? If yes please let me know how?

Answer (score 1):

For styling `TextView`s programmatically, you must have a style inheriting a `TextAppearance` style, and you can apply it using the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) { textView.setTextAppearance(context,android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small); } else { textView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom style in style.xml like this:

```
<style name="MyHeadlineTextAppearance" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"/>
```

Then set it to your TextView as below:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.MyHeadlineTextAppearance);
```